# Render a specific section in mvc views based on Roles and some condition

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authorization, asp.net-identity, roles

```
I have a requirement to render 4 buttons (Add, Delete, Read, Update) in a view based on the following conditions:

i) Each user can have multiple roles. 
ii) Each roles will have specific permissions for each pages.
```

The following are the tables I designed.

```
Table Page: 
   i) PageId 
  ii) Page Name 
 iii) Controller Name 
  iv) Action Name

Table Role 
   i) RoleId 
  ii) Role Name

Table UserRole 
   i) UserId 
  ii) RoleId

Table Permission 
   i) PermissionId 
  ii) RoleId 
 iii) PageId 
  iv) CanRead <--- Boolean
   v) CanAdd  <--- Boolean
  vi) CanDelete <--- Boolean
 vii) CanUpdate <--- Boolean
viii) Controller Name 
  ix) Action Name




  UserId               RoleId
    -------------------- -----------
    2                    1
    2                    2
    4                    2
    5                    2
```

Data stored in UserRole table

```
Id          RoleId      PageId      CanView CanInsert CanUpdate CanDelete
    ----------- ----------- ----------- ------- --------- --------- ---------
    1           1           1           1       0         1         1
    2           1           2           1       0         0         1
    3           1           3           0       0         1         1
    4           2           1           0       0         0         0
    5           2           2           1       1         0         0
    6           2           3           0       0         1         1



Data Stored in permission table.
```

eg: Role Admin can have permission to Read, Delete, Add or Update in User page. The same role might just have only Read permission in Employee page.
    Wherever, a user browse to a certain page the 4 buttons should be render based on his role and permissions set for that particular page. Also, a user can have both Admin and User roles at the same time.

I hope I am making sense and convey my requirement properly.

Comment: Hello Sahidul, Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried so far? 
Please show us your code.
Also, would you really need a user who can delete or update, but can't view the data?

Comment: Hi @Dragonthoughts, I thought of using Identity claims but that doesn't suffice my requirement as it was getting too messy. Also, I don't want to hit the DB everytime I browse to a page. Yes, the user can view the data but buttons should not be visible.  I want something of this sort in view.  `@if (mp.CanView)
    {
        <button> View </button>
    }
    if (mp.CanInsert)
    {
        <button> Insert </button>
    }
    if (mp.CanUpdate)
    {
        <button> Update </button>
    }
    if (mp.CanDelete)
    {
        <button> delete </button>
    }`

Comment: Please edit your question to include your update.

Comment: If you separate your functionality, for each into its own function that has a single responsibility, then your code will be easier to obtain and you can use attributes to enforce the claims, keeping your code even cleaner.